# Documentation lint to Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, static-analysis, lint

I have a lint for forcing documentation to class, function or a member class in dart language

Link to the documentation lint: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/public_member_api_docs.html

I wonder if there is a similar linter or tool to Javascript?

Comment: @Liam I don't ask for alternatives or recommendations..what I want 1 option to an existing feature in dart language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSLint](https://www.jslint.com/help.html) for javascript or [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) for typescript can force JSDoc style documentation.

Or In ESLint, the doc rule name is  "require-jsdoc"
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-jsdoc

and "valid-jsdoc" https://eslint.org/docs/rules/valid-jsdoc

But these rules are deprecated in ESLint v3.0
So the alternative which is recommended by ESLint team is https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc

Comment: Can you please detail how to enable JSDoc enforcement?

Comment: @Bergi I updated the answer to the required rule
You can add static analysis to your git push command in this path .git/hooks/pre-push

Comment: Uh, jslint is not the same as eslint?

Comment: @Bergi oops I updated the answer with wrong tool name anyway es is ECMAScript which is js.